# Magento admin: New block not showing after adding in layout

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have several custom blocks added in an admin page under my custom module. When I try to add another block by adding an entry in the layout file of my module, the new block does not display. Am I missing anything?

My existing block that is displaying well.

```
<block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_shipping_method" template="sales/order/create/abstract.phtml" name="shipping_method">
     <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_shipping_method_form" template="xxxx/xxxx/quote/create/shipping/form.phtml" name="form" />
 </block>
```

The block I am trying to add below it, and it is not displaying

```
<block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_billing_method" template="sales/order/create/abstract.phtml" name="billing_method">
                            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_billing_method_form" template="xxx/xxx/quote/create/billing/form.phtml" name="form" />
                        </block>
```

BTW, the block is loading if I keep it inside the already existing block. Wondering how can I make it appear outside the existing one, as a standalone block.

```
<block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_shipping_method" template="sales/order/create/abstract.phtml" name="shipping_method">
                            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_shipping_method_form" template="xxxx/xxxxxx/quote/create/shipping/form.phtml" name="shipping_form" />   
  <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_billing_method" template="sales/order/create/abstract.phtml" name="billing_method">
   <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_billing_method_form" template="xxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/quote/create/billing/form.phtml" name="billing_form" />
   </block>  
</block>
```

Comment: What version of Magento are you running? If 1.9.2.2 or you have applied patches 6788 and above you might find that blocks need to be manually enabled in System > Permissions > Blocks and System > Permissions > Variables. See [here](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details) for more details

Comment: That is not the case with blocks being added programmatically. Just for static blocks :)

Comment: Ah I get ya, It's just that I had a similar issue and that was my fix. Sorry!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed the issue. I had a data.phtml template file in the same folder my other phtml files were in, in which there was following code.

```
    <div id="order-billing_method" style="display:none"><?php echo  $this->getChildHtml('billing_method') ?></div>
```

I changed the display:none to display:block and the new block of billing-method started showing without any problem. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: I have a similar problem with not showing  a custom block on admin page. In my case, I want the custom block to be appear in adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_view. If you don't mind, take a look at this unresolved question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39340112/adding-block-into-adminhtml-shipment-view

thank's in advance

Answer (score 2):

Can you change the name attribute?
For example

```
<block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_shipping_method" template="sales/order/create/abstract.phtml" name="shipping_method">
     <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_shipping_method_form" template="xxxx/xxxx/quote/create/shipping/form.phtml" name="shipping_form" />
 </block>
```

and

```
<block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_billing_method" template="sales/order/create/abstract.phtml" name="billing_method">
                            <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_billing_method_form" template="xxx/xxx/quote/create/billing/form.phtml" name="billing_form" />
                        </block>
```

And after, refresh cache

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Edited my question. The block is loading when I put it inside the existing block. But I still need it to be outside as a standalone block.